# Changing Location Settings - Android Tutorial

Tags: android, location

I am currently trying to implement code that will request change for the location settings. I am currently following the Android Studio Tutoriel to do so.

However, when I followed the tutorial and put the code inside the actual Studio, I saw it came up with several errors.

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder LSBuilder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        LSBuilder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        final PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient,LSBuilder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can
                        // initialize location requests here.
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                        // by showing the user a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way
                        // to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.

                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Firstly,

```
final LocationSettingsStates = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
```

comes up with an error of Unexpected Token. I am not quite sure what's wrong here. There does seem to be any additional information. Secondly,

```
status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
```

In there, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS is undefined. I am not quite sure what I should define it as or anything.

Can anyone explain the above two errors?

Answer (score 1):

`LocationSettingsStates` is just a type, you need to specify where to store the object of the type. Replace:

```
final LocationSettingsStates = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
```

with:

```
final LocationSettingsStates states = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
```

I believe `REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS` is just an unique identifier you set for the callback, so declare it in your class as:

```
private final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0; // a unique identifier
```